# Retrieve a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, analytics

```
print(pd.read_excel(File,Sheet_Name,0,None,0,None,["Column_Name"],1))
```

Since i am a noob to pandas i want to retrive a column of ExcelSheet using pandas in the form of array. I tried the code above but it didn't really work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should also update your question using the edit link below to show 'what didn't really work' Its always good to show errors etc. you might want to look at what makes a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(File,sheetname=Sheet_Name)

print(df['column_name'])
```

Comment: Adding to the above, any field in the column can be accessed as `pd['column_name'][record_no]` e.g `pd['column_name'][2]`

Comment: column_name should be in closed parentheses

Comment: print(pd['Rep'])
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: There is a problem .....actually i wanted to retrive column in some kind of list so that i can plot a scatter graph in "matplotlib.pyplot" but it accepts only list as arguments for the variables but here the variable is of object type! :/

Comment: Use list(df['column_name']) to convert a column to a list

Comment: return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pencil' .